# Can Hibernate Tools reverse-engineer DB entities with annotations instead of cfg.xml files?

Tags: java, hibernate, reverse-engineering

I have a number of database tables I need to reverse-engineer POJOs for.   I've gotten as far as getting the bare POJOs created as well as the  cfg.xml files:

Simple POJO:

```
public class AddressType implements java.io.Serializable {
    private long addressId;
    private char addressType;
    private String addressDescription;
}
```

Simple cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mycompany.model.Addytyp" table="ADDYTYP" schema="XX" catalog="BANANA">
        <comment>Address Types</comment>
        <id name="addressType" type="char">
            <column name="ADDRESS_TYPE" length="1" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="addressId" type="long">
            <column name="ADDRESS_ID" precision="10" scale="0" not-null="true">
                <comment>Address ID</comment>
            </column>
        </property>
        <property name="addressDescription" type="string">
            <column name="ADDRESS_DESCRIPTION" length="25" not-null="true">
                <comment>Address Decription</comment>
            </column>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

What I was wondering is, is there a setting or a tool that will reverse-engineer the POJOs with the column and ID information as annotations in the POJO instead of in a separate file?  For example:

Simple POJO with Annotations:

```
@Table(name="ADDYTYP")
public class AddressType implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column( name="ADDRESS_ID", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true)
    private long addressId;

    @Column(name="ADDRESS_TYPE", length=1)
    private char addressType;

    @Column( name="ADDRESS_DESCRIPTION", length=25 nullable=true)
    private String addresDescription;
}
```

Anyone know of a setting or a tool that will do this?

Comment: Are you using the eclipse plugin or the netbeans plugin?

Comment: I was actually using the ant task.   It was a simple case of not reading the instructions.   :)  Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duh.   This one is so simple I'm embarrassed I asked it.   This is a simple matter of configuration of the Hibernate Tools task.   The relevant documentation is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/ant.html#d0e4821).

The Ant POJO generation task, properly configured to generate annotations, looks like this:

```
<hbm2java  jdk5="true" ejb3="true" />
```

These options default to "false" for some reason.  From the Hibernate docs:

```
jdk     Code will contain JDK 5 constructs 
        such as generics and static imports (Default = False)
ejb3    Code will contain EJB 3 features, e.g. using annotations 
        from javax.persistence and org.hibernate.annotations    (Default = False)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would like to ask if do you know how to generate column annotations set to the fields instead of the getters and setters? thanks =)

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul - I don't know that off the top of my head, sorry.   I moved on from Hibernate quite a while ago.   I wish I could help!